# New Laravel projects always starts with 20mb

Tags: laravel, memory

Every time I start a new Laravel project, after installing the Laravel debug bar the memory is 20 MB. I’m fairly certain it should be 4 MB or 5 MB. I’ve even tried clockwork, still 20 MB, After researching the problem I discovered it's usually a Windows issue. Just one problem I'm not using Windows, I’m using Xammp on a Linux Mint operating system, and I can’t seem to find a solution. Any ideas as to why this might be?